# How can we document the socio-professional standing required for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, paperwork

My family and I are planning a holiday trip to Italy from India.

I was reading the list of documents required for our visa application and saw a requirement to document our socio-professional standing.

I can provide school records or income-tax returns for me and my father.

The real problem is my mother doesn't have any of the documents requested in order to show her socio-professional standing. She's a housewife and does not have any educational qualifications, so there are no school records for her.

Are there any other ways to document the socio-professional standing for her?

Comment: What type of visa are you seeking?

Comment: @Relaxed Tourism visa for not more than 8-10 days..

Comment: Is your mother travelling with her spouse (maybe your father?) or only with you?

Comment: @Relaxed yes shes travellig with her spouse i.e my father

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mother does not have something to show for socio-professional, she can still submit documents on the strength of her social standing (i.e., the 'socio' part of socio-professional).

Examples would include, her marriage certificate, church/religious memberships, other memberships and affiliations that demonstrate an engagement with society.  A reference from the family doctor might be helpful, but shouldn't be seen as *required*.

Since she is applying as part of a family group, it is unlikely to make a big difference either way.  They are aware that not every applicant has  formal credentials and as long as the primary is acceptable they will normally grant the dependant relatives a visa also.